# React Native app won't build, package com.swmansion.reanimated does not exist

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I inherited a React Native app from consultants and am trying to get it to build on Android. When I run npx react-native run-android, the build fails due to a package not existing.

```
/Users/justintoth/Dev/m365-mobile-app/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java:81: error: package com.swmansion.reanimated does not exist
import com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedPackage;
                               ^
/Users/justintoth/Dev/m365-mobile-app/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java:172: error: cannot find symbol
      new ReanimatedPackage(),
          ^
  symbol:   class ReanimatedPackage
  location: class PackageList
Note: /Users/justintoth/Dev/m365-mobile-app/android/app/src/debug/java/com/marriage365/app/ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2 errors
```

I tried to npm install the react-native-reanimated dependency, however I still get the same error. Any ideas of how to get past this error?

Here is the packages.json file: https://gist.github.com/justintoth/86f65a44c15e85954e478310855e33ea

Here is the full build log: https://gist.github.com/justintoth/11b462c7dbe0f51a2e78a62950e2b969

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: @red-devil I wasn't able to yet. I'm having to use old versions of node and npm (via nvm) for this project for now.

Comment: @Justin any update? I'm fighting with the same error at the moment.